# Swift - 1.2, Parse - 1.7.4, CachePolicy

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, ios8, xcode6

I am trying to retrieve a query from the Parse database; however, when I run the app and click the button to go to the view controller that is going to retrieve the data from the database, my app crashes. When the app crashes, I get sent the AppDelegate.swift file.

This is the error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Method not allowed when Pinning is enabled.'

I made sure to implemented Parse correctly in my project. Also, when I take out the if self.objects.count == 0 {} code block, the app runs fine when I go to the view controller that is retrieving the data from the database. But only this time, there are no objects in my tableview list when there are objects in my parse database. Thanks in advance.

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    let query = PFUser.query()

    if searchInProgress {
        // We are looking for the string contents in the search bar to match the names in the parse username category.
        query?.whereKey("username", containsString: searchString)
    }

    // From the objects aleady loaded...
    if self.objects?.count == 0{
        // If we have not already loaded the elements from our database, then it will use the elements that have already been downloaded when we have already run the app
        query?.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheThenNetwork
    }

    query?.orderByAscending("username")
    return query!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use pinning and cache policy at the same time, hence the inconsistency exception. [image: From Parse docs]
http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/cachePolicy